# Date issue in MYSQLIMPORT for 9999 year

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am loading data into MySQL by using mysqlimport. And the script is as given below:

```
mysqlimport -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -h $HOST -P $PORT $INSTANCE  --fields-terminated-by '\t' --local -v $STG_DIR"/"$MYSQL_TABLE
```

While loading data into MySQL except timestamp column which is having `9999-12-31 00:01:00.000000` remaining columns are loading fine. For that particular column it is giving just warning and loading with `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`.

I also tried to load by using tools like mysqlyog and MySQL workbench as well, but I am getting the same issue.

Below is the example:

Data in my Unix file:

```
3       2007-04-27 13:56:49.805695      2007-04-27 16:00:02.571438 
23659   2006-02-12 00:01:00.0           9999-12-31 00:01:00.0
```

After loading into MySQL using above script:

```
3       2006-02-12 00:01:00 2007-04-27 13:56:50 
23659   2006-02-12 00:01:00 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Issue columns is 3rd: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

When I update manually for same column with `9999-12-31 00:01:000` also I am getting same result:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

But when I did manual update for same column with `2000-12-31 00:01:00` I am getting correct value which I updated like `2000-12-31 00:01:00`

Comment: Just to comment: "do the needful" - this is something you tell your service provider or a partner, or a subordinate. Not when you ask for hel

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nico... Yes you are correct, TIMESTAMP has limit, so i have changed to DATETIME.

TIMESTAMP: It is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC.

DATETIME: It is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. The supported range is 1000-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of this column?

If it's a `TIMESTAMP`, it will not be able to accept dates beyond 2038-01-19 03:14:07.

In this case, you must use the type `DATETIME` instead.

---

MySql manual : [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

> ```
> TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19
> 03:14:07' UTC
> For DATETIME, the supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
> ```

Year 2038 problem : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

> The Year 2038 problem is caused by insufficient capacity of the chosen data type (a signed 32-bit integer)

Max value of a signed 32-bits integer is 2147483647 (second after the first january 1970)

When you convert it into date time, you get `2038-01-19 03:14:07`

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer by editing it, instead of linking to external sites